# How to set the color of matching braces in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I wish to have a more emphasis on the brackets match, so I set it to yellow and bold in the options. However, when I place my cursor next to a curly brace (also parenthesis, brackets etc.) it still only flags with washed-out gray...

How do I set the color to my liking?

The setting I've made was:

Tools → Options → Environment → Font and Colors
- Brace Matching (Highlight)
- Brace Matching (Rectangle)

Comment: Yeah, this seems borked in 2015 CTP6. And the default "highlight" is extremely difficult to see. Seems to be a Connect issue, but it ain't loading for me: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1033540/braces-are-not-highlighted-correctly-in-c

Comment: @KentBoogaart Put it as a reply, please.

Comment: Also experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just tried it with the RC release we shipped this week and also seeing the problem. Will follow up with the team and get this fixed. I'll post updates here. Thanks for sharing the problem!

Update: I confirmed with the team that this is a known issue and is on the list to get fixed.

Comment: Any idea on time frame for that? Are we talking weeks, months or quarters?

Comment: It's now fixed, but I'm not sure what release train it will catch. You can see more details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/2520).

Comment: @GusP, what about this related, reported issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155034/how-to-change-the-braces-parenthesis-colors-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @BrianPickens, just answered the question. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: In case this is still an issue for anyone, I always solve this (and other theming tweaks) with the [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) (find it through `Tools → Extensions and Updates...` dialog). Simply edit the theme, switch to "show all elements" mode (top-left) and search for `Brace`. You want `Text Editor → Brace Matching → (Fore|Back)ground`. Click "Save and apply" (also top-left)

Answer (score 12):

Tools → Options → Environment → Font and Colors → Punctuations

Affects all parentheses, commas etc.

On dark view it defaults to black over black

Comment: This always sets the color for braces, etc.. OP wanted to highlight *matching* braces.

Comment: Punctuations On VS 2015 punctuations is under the 'Display Items' list

Comment: Puntiations, nice...  This work for me. Color braces and Parenhtesis.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper also applies color to matching braces. You can turn this off in ReSharper options and then your VS color setting should be applied.

Comment: The issue was with a specific (and now obsolete) version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by copying my customized theme to a new name, then made copy the 'current' theme. Then went into Fonts & Colors and set them for my preferences.

My braces were always disappearing into a big black rectangle (always 2 braces, matched or not). The blackness would not go away until I typed a Space or other character. Drove me up a wall...!