# Visual studio 2015 highlight block between brackets { }

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I recently got Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 enterprise RC. In this screenshot i'm using C#. I highlight the brackets, but the block inside those brackets isn't getting highlighted as it used to in Visual studio 2013 Ultimate. There is no indication of where those brackets end.

Can I change that ?

[image: 1]

Visual Studio 2013:

[image: 2]

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 highlights blocks delimited by braces? I never knew! How did you set that up?

Comment: It's actually there, just very light and hard to distinguish (talking about the highlighted closing bracer, not the entire code section). Change the contrast settings on your monitor.

Comment: @OmriAharon I had to look closely (to say the least) to see that. Is there any way you know of, to bring it back like the older 2013 version ?

Comment: Happened to me frequently as well when I changed versions. I never touched the VS settings to my recollection, just increased (I think) the contrast in my monitor settings and it solved it right up.

Comment: @stakx My wording is not very clear I agree. I was talking about highlighting the end brackets, or give any clear indication of where that bracket { } block is.

Comment: Btw, Ctrl+] jumps to closing/starting bracer, just as an addition to the highlighted indication. Sometimes, hopefully not too frequently, the block is too long :)

Comment: The answer I shared on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756510/how-to-set-the-color-of-matching-braces-in-vs-2015/29988532?noredirect=1#comment48670043_29988532) should apply here as well.

Comment: @GusP I think the bug is that in the light version of VS the bracket highlight is `light gray` and its the same in VS dark. Problem is that in VS dark background is almost the exact same color so you can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the Brace Matching (rectangle) in VS 2015 RC. It's a known bug.

[duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756510/how-to-set-the-color-of-matching-braces-in-vs-2015)