# Highlight Matching Brace In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, highlight

In Notepad++ for example when your cursor is next to a brace it will highlight the corresponding opening or closing brace on screen.

Check out the link below for a example as to what I mean.
http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/visualassist/visualassist._match.html

How can Visual Studio do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2013 C# editor has brace highlighting.  Place the cursor on the outside of the brace, (not the inside) to see the highlight.

[image: Default Brace color]

The default color is very subtle, use the **Tools\Options\Fonts And Colors** setting to apply a different highlight color.

[image: Fonts and Colors setting]

[image: New Brace Color]

Comment: Is there a way to have this work on xml files and other files? Not just C# ones?

Comment: What to you want to match in the XML file?  The elements?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, I had to change the `Brace Matching` display item rather than `Brace Matching (Rectangle)`, to notice the color.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury, yes, In VS 2015, there is an additional entry Brace Matching, which is the correct setting to change the values.  I think it has to do with this bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756510/how-to-set-the-color-of-matching-braces-in-vs-2015

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, have to change the `Brace Matching` instead of the `Brace Matching (Rectangle)`.
Thanks to Walt, that is very helpful especially I change the background to grey. So if the background for brace matching is also grey, the brace could not stand out.

Comment: Is there a way to see the matching brace if it is not currently on the screen?

Comment: @Zack  You can move to the other brace with Ctrl+]

Comment: I realise this is an old question but I can't see any reason why this answer hasn't been accepted.

Comment: Is there a way to find the matching brace if I am inside the brace?

Comment: It works halfway in VS 2022. It honors the setting in C# files, but completely ignores it for Javascript. Is there some other setting that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

### For Visual Studio 2022

The setting is slightly different:
Environments > Fonts and Colors > **Brace Matching**

#### Quick way to get there

Ctrl + Q -> type "fonts and colors" and hit enter.

#### Example

set to Teal
[image]

#### Result

[image]