# Problem with highlight in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[this is the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxcY5.png)

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code:

I'm programming with Dart with the support of Flutter's framework but everytime I open a parenthesis, VS highlight everything that I write inside of them and it doesn't give me suggestions about the properties of that Widget.

How can I disable this function? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution to see if it works:
[Highlight Matching Brace In Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678299/highlight-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)

Try Brace Maching (hightlight).